# limit the speed of writing files to NFS

Tags: centos, rsync, nfs

CentOS 5.6

NFS is mounted on the server for backup disk space. When the backup job started, it could reach 80MB/s and we really do not expect it took so much bandwidth. So i need to find a way to limit the speed of writing to NFS.

I tried **rsync** with **--bwlimit=5000**. However, it did limit the reading speed, but the accumulated data still was written at 80MB/s, and no writing activities for seconds.

Is there any way to limit the writing speed of NFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for opening such an old thread, but I wrote a little script to limit speed tranfer using the `pv` command, it works over NFS as well. The only thing I haven't gotten over yet is a drop of speed, it happens only when I use NFS over sshfs everything is fine.

My server NFS configuration (the exports):

```
rw,sync,no_subtree_check
```

And the client configuration (mount options):

```
rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr,_netdev,noauto,hard,sync
```

Here's my script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 # Simple Script to mv files OR folders at $3 BPS  

tor_path="$1"  
mv_dir="$2"  
speed="$3"  
tor_dir="$(basename "$tor_path")"  
file=""  
tlines=""  
cnt=""   
file=""  

[[ "$mv_dir" != *"/" ]] && mv_dir=""$mv_dir"/"  

if [[ -f "$tor_path" ]] && [[ -d "$mv_dir" ]]  
  then  
  pv -L "$speed" "$tor_path" > "$mv_dir""$tor_dir"  
elif [[ -d "$tor_path" ]] && [[ -d "$mv_dir" ]]  
  then  
    tor_files="$(mktemp --tmpdir tor_files.XXXXXX)"  
    [[ "$tor_path" != *"/" ]] && tor_path=""$tor_path"/"  

    find "$tor_path" -type d > "$tor_files"  
    sed 's#'"$tor_path"'#'"$tor_dir"'/#g; s###g' -i "$tor_files"  

    tlines="$(wc -l < "$tor_files")"   
    cnt=0  
    while [ "$cnt" -lt "$tlines" ]  
      do  
        let cnt++  
        file="$(head -n $cnt $tor_files | tail -1)"  
        mkdir "$mv_dir""$file"  
    done  

    find "$tor_path" -type f > "$tor_files"  
    sed 's#'"$tor_path"'#'"$tor_dir"'/#g' -i "$tor_files"  

    tlines="$(wc -l < "$tor_files")"  
    cnt=0  
    while [ "$cnt" -lt "$tlines" ]  
      do  
        let cnt++  
        file="$(head -n $cnt $tor_files | tail -1)"  
        pv -L "$speed" "$tor_path""$(basename "$file")" > "$mv_dir""$file"  
    done  

    rm "$tor_files"  
else  
    exit 1    
fi
```

Answer (score 6):

NFS does not supply a method to limit the bandwidth used by the client.

The behaviour you're seeing where data accumulates and is then written out at full speed is the dirty pages growing on the client and then being flushed out to the NFS server. This is the expected way that IO works.

On a Linux NFS client, you can use `tc` to match and control traffic. This would be as simple as making a class with the NFS server's IP address as the destination, and ratelimiting that class.

This is covered in the [Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control HOWTO](http://lartc.org/howto/), specifically in Chapter 9 *Queueing Disciplines for Bandwidth Management* and within `man tc`.

Here is an example of the exact commands to use: http://iomem.com/archives/17-Rate-limiting-with-sch_htb.html